# Select 10 rows for each id in

Tags: mysql

How I can get 10 rows for each id_recipient ?

```
SELECT id FROM msg WHERE id_recipient IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

So request should return 50 rows(10 rows for each id_recipient)

Comment: Separate statements selecting data for one id each, limiting the results to 10, all stuffed together via UNION …

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? In 8.0 you can use window functions, otherwise you have to use variables.

Comment: ...or (slower) some other method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` (MySQL 8.0+):

```
SELECT sub.id
FROM (SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_recipient ORDER BY some_col) AS rn
     FROM msg 
     WHERE id_recipient IN (1,2,3,4,5)) AS sub
WHERE rn <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method - although it doesn't scale particularly well...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+-----+
| entryID | ID  |
+---------+-----+
|     331 | 136 |
|     332 | 136 |
|     333 | 136 |
|     334 | 136 |
|     335 | 136 |
|     336 | 136 |
|     337 | 137 |
|     338 | 137 |
|     339 | 137 |
|     340 | 137 |
+---------+-----+

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.entryid <= x.entryid 
 GROUP  
    BY x.entryid 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=3;
+---------+-----+
| entryID | ID  |
+---------+-----+
|     331 | 136 |
|     332 | 136 |
|     333 | 136 |
|     337 | 137 |
|     338 | 137 |
|     339 | 137 |
+---------+-----+
```

...and here's a method that scales well, but perhaps MySQL8.0's modern methods are better.

```
SELECT a.entryid
     , a.id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := id
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev := null, @i:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY entryid
     ) a
 WHERE i <=3
 ORDER
    BY entryid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not the chance to be in MYSQL 8.0 :

```
SELECT sub.id
FROM (SELECT id,
         @cnt := IF(@last_id = id , @cnt +1, 1) AS dummy_cnt,
         @last_id := id AS dummy_id
     FROM msg 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0, @last_id:= 0) var
     WHERE id_recipient IN (1,2,3,4,5)
     ORDER BY id) AS sub
WHERE dummy_cnt <= 10
ORDER BY sub.id;
```

Comment: Note that if using this method, you can (and, in my view, should) initialise the variables within the query itself. Also, you should always include an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Although not strictly necessary (because the order of the sequential entryids is self evident), for good measure, you should have an additional ORDER BY clause at the end too.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.5+

Note the queries are not tested so they might contain a error.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 
       msg.*
     , (CASE WHEN @id = msg.id THEN @rank := @rank + 1 ELSE @rank := 1 END) AS rank
     , (@id := msg.id) AS init_id
  FROM 
   msg 
  WHERE
   msg.id_recipient IN(1,2,3,4,5)
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @id := 0, @rank := 0) AS init_user_variables
  ORDER BY
   msg.some_column ASC
) AS msg_ranked
WHERE
 msg_ranked.rank <= 10
```

For all MySQL versions and most databases but very slow because off the co-related subquery.

```
SELECT 
 *
 , (
     SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS rank
     FROM 
      msg msgInner
     WHERE           
          msgInner.id_recipient = msgOuter.id_recipient 
        AND
          msgInner.id > msgOuter.id
     ORDER BY
      msgInner.some_column ASC

   ) AS rank
FROM 
 msg msgOuter
WHERE
   msgOuter.id_recipient IN(1,2,3,4,5)
 AND
   rank <= 10
```